# Zookeeper zkcli howto inherit ACL from parent?

Tags: acl, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to inherit the ACLs from the parent znode when creating a child with zkcli (zookeeper v3.4.6)? 
I can't find help on the syntax, and if I specify no acl, it gives world instead of the parent ACL:

```
[zk: zookeeper3(CONNECTED) 2] addauth digest user1:pass
[zk: zookeeper3(CONNECTED) 4] create /parent "" auth:user1:crdwa
Created /parent
[zk: zookeeper3(CONNECTED) 5] getAcl /parent
'digest,'user1:UZIsvOKp29j8vAahJzjgpA1VTOk=
: cdrwa
[zk: zookeeper3(CONNECTED) 6] create /parent/child ""   
Created /parent/child
[zk: zookeeper3(CONNECTED) 8] getAcl /parent/child
'world,'anyone
: cdrwa
```

Thanks.

Comment: In zookeeper ,you have to apply ACL to every znode. So the child will not inherit the parent ACLs. If you want it you can create a wrapper on top of the create call.

Comment: Apache zookeeper does not support ACL inheritance. You are required to set ACL for each znode that you create.